# PHP Substracting 1 day from date string php doesnt work

Tags: php, date

i am trying to substract 1 day from date string, if condition is met.

If condition (if time between 12-16) works fine, but outcome of yesterday's date is wrong.

This is what i tried with research from stackoverflow:

```
<?php
#trying to remove 1 day from date
$date = date("d/m/y");
    if (date('H') < 16 && date('H') > 12) {
        $date2 = strtotime(date('d/m/y') . ' -1 day');
        $date2 = date('d/m/y', $date2);
    }
echo "Todays date is {$date} and yesterday was {$date2}";
?>
```

Outcome from phpfiddle:

> Todays date is 23/10/16 and yesterday was 31/12/69

Can someone share some light on it, how it should be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead

```
$date2 = strtotime(date('d/m/y') . ' -1 day');
```

use

```
 $date2 = strtotime('-1 day');
```